# Hide and show shapes when the CheckBox is Checked

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on WPF C# project and trying to show my shape through `CheckBox` (if it is `Checked`, the shape will shown ). 
I did

```
Visibility triangle = Visibility.Hidden;        

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Visibility triangle = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Polygon MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="shape_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
    MouseLeftButtonUp="shape_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="shape_MouseMove" 
    AllowDrop="True" x:Name="triangle" Stroke="Purple" StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Left="482"
    Canvas.Top="176" Height="30" Width="41">
    <Polygon.Fill> 
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.4"/> 
    </Polygon.Fill> 
</Polygon>
```

It still not working. Is there another way to show or hide shapes in WPF? Or can you help me finding the problem with my code?

Comment: What is your shape's name?

Comment: the name is triangle

Comment: `triangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`

Comment: <Polygon
            MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="shape_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
            MouseLeftButtonUp="shape_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
            MouseMove="shape_MouseMove" 
            AllowDrop="True"  
                           
            x:Name="triangle"
                         <Polygon.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.4"/>
                </Polygon.Fill>
           </Polygon>

Comment: @chris I cannot understand the question, please can you publish your xaml code?

Comment: <Polygon
            x:Name="triangle"
            Stroke="Purple" 
            StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Left="482" Canvas.Top="176"       Height="30" Width="41">                        
            </Polygon>

Comment: @IIan, I want to show the shape if I thick the checkbutton. So if it is not thicked yet, there is no shape appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you didn't do anything. You just declare a variable of type `Visibility` and set it's value to `Visibility.Visible`. You didn't visible your shape. So change this:

```
Visibility triangle = Visibility.Visible;
```

To this:

```
triangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Although I can't see the `Points` property in your `Polygon`. If you don't specify the `Points` it's not showing. Set `Point` like this:

```
<Polygon  AllowDrop="True" x:Name="triangle" Points="50, 100 200, 100 200, 200 300, 30" ...>
```